# Enlarging image in CSS lightbox

Tags: css, html, image, lightbox

As a newbie at CSS, I'm still in the learning phase, so please bear with me.  I have a lightbox constructed entirely in CSS, and I want to generate larger images (the images within the lightbox, not the thumbnails on the main page) than the ones that are currently displayed, but cannot think of any way to achieve this!

Live website: http://contractoptions.com/gallery2.html

HTML:

```
<ul class="gallery">
<li>
    <a href="#img1"><img src="thumb-01.jpg" alt="Image 1 Thumb"></a>
    <article id="img1">
        <figure>
            <a href="#img2"><img src="img01.jpg" alt="Image 1"></a>
        </figure>
        <nav>
            <a class="close" href="#close">Close</a>
            <a class="arrow prev" href="#img25">Previous</a>
    <a class="arrow next" href="#img2">Next</a>
        </nav>
    </article>
</li>
```

CSS:

/* ----- Gallery Page ----- */

```
.container {
width: 110%;
padding: 0 4%;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0 20px;
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
    height: 50%
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

.gallery {
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #666;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 15px #98b277;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

    .gallery li {
        float: right;
        width: 18%;
        margin: 1%;
    }

        .gallery li > a {
            float: right;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(.5) sepia(.8);
            -webkit-transition: .5s;
            transition: .5s;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        }

            .gallery li > a img {
                max-width: 100%;
                float: right;
                display: block;
                box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
                -webkit-transition: .5s;
                transition: .5s;
            }

            .gallery li > a:hover {
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) sepia(0);
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .gallery li > a img:hover {
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
                -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
                transform: scale(1.4);
                box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
            }

        .gallery article {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .gallery article:target {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 100px 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
            z-index: 1000;
        }    

            .gallery article figure {
                height: 100%;
            }

            .gallery article img {
                opacity: 0;
                -webkit-transition: .7s;
                transition: .7s;
                border: 10px solid #fff;
                max-height: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            }

            .gallery article:target img {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            .gallery figcaption {
                background: rgba(250, 250, 250, .1);
                padding: 5px 10px;
                font-size: 1.3em;
                font-style: italic;
                color: #999;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }

                article .close {
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 50%;
                    top: 40px;
                    margin-left: -50px;
                    width: 100px;
                    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, .9);
                    color: #333;
                    border-radius: 15px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    padding: 6px 6px 6px 25px;
                    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    -webkit-transition: .5s;
                    transition: .5s;
                }

                    article .close:before {
                        content: "X";
                        color: #fff;
                        font-family: Arial;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        position: absolute;
                        padding-top: 3px;
                        top: 3px;
                        left: 5px;
                        width: 24px;
                        height: 21px;
                        background: #666;
                        border-radius: 50%;
                    }

                    article .close:hover {
                        background: #fff;
                    }

                article .arrow {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 250px;
                    width: 0;
                    height: 0;
                    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
                    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
                    text-indent: -9999px;
                    -webkit-transition: .4s;
                    transition: .4s;
                }

                article .prev {
                    left: 50%;
                    margin-left: -35%;
                    border-right: 60px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, .1);
                }

                article .prev:hover {
                    border-right-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
                }

                article .next {
                    right: 50%;
                    margin-right: -35%;
                    border-left: 60px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, .1);
                }

                article .next:hover {
                    border-left-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
                }


@media screen and (max-width:1100px) {

article .arrow {
    top: 36px;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

article .prev {
    margin-left: -130px;
    border-right: 40px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, .3);
}

article .next {
    margin-right: -130px;
    border-left: 40px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, .3);
}

}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {

h1 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

.gallery li {
    width: 23%;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width:450px) {

h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.gallery li {
    width: 31%;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width:350px) {

h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.gallery li {
    width: 48%;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a quick [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jamesfinn/pen/aFvEA) for you. I simply plugged in some placeholder images, and no matter what size image I use, it is not restricted by your CSS. My suggestion? Simply upload bigger images. To fiddle around with my settings, configure placehold.it images like so:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
```

Where `200x200` can be whatever dimensions you like.

EDITED UPDATE FOLLOWS HERE:

At first, I thought you wanted to increase the size of the lightboxed image. But now I think you are probably talking about the size of the images in the gallery, which are constrained by this declaration in your CSS:

```
.gallery li > a img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Therefore, the images in your gallery will not be able to grow past 100% the width of their parent.

Comment: Your second statement is correct; I do want the images in gallery to be larger, but it would appear there is no way to expand the size unless I upload larger images.  I did attempt to change the max-width initially, but all it did was distort the placement of the image and navigation arrows within the lightbox.

Comment: Uploading larger images won't do it: The `img`'s are constrained to 100% of the parent `li` elements, which are in turn constrained to 18% of their parent, the `ul.gallery` element, which is set to `max-width:700px`. The end result is that your gallery `img`'s will not grow past roughly 120px.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to move past this? One of the very first things I did was change the parent size, (I thought that was the problem as well) the result being the main page with the thumbnails grows larger, not the images contained in the lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise the fact that CSS can be targeted according to which anchor is active in a page:

```
<figure id="image-01-in-document">
    <a href="#show-01-in-lightbox">
        <img alt="Some thumbnail" src="/_res/thumb/01.jpg" />
        <p>Some Thumbnail's caption.</p>
    </a>
</figure>
```

When someone clicks on the thumbnail they whatever has the ID of `show-01-in-lightbox` will become active. Here you can put your larger images. We use the `figure` with ID `image-01-in-document` to return to the thumbnail from the lightbox:

```
<aside class="lightbox" id="show-01-in-lightbox">
    <a href="#image-01-in-document">
        <img alt="Some big image" src="/_res/fullsize/01.jpg" />
        <p>Some Lightbox's caption.</p>
    </a>
</aside>
```

All we need is some CSS to hook onto the active/inactive states of `image-01-in-document` and `show-01-in-lightbox`:

```
aside.lightbox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

aside.lightbox:target {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

By default the lightbox images are hidden. However, should you click on the thumbnail then `aside.lightbox:target` is activated and the lightbox image suddenly appears. Transitions can be added etc. All you need is a host of asides for each lightbox image at the end of a document.

At least, that's my interpretation of a CSS only lightbox.